Why can't we call a function in Dart's constant constructor?
I have read the benefits of const constructors in :
How does the const constructor actually work?
However, in this case, I feel like the change yet minor significantly improve readability when using functions and extensions.
Abstruse code  :
class MyLatLng {
  const MyLatLng({required double lat, required double lng})
      : lat = lat < -90.0 ? -90.0 : (90.0 < lat ? 90.0 : lat),
        lng = lng >= -180 && lng < 180 ? lng : (lng + 180.0) % 360.0 - 180.0;

}

Conspicuous (Better):
class MyLatLng {
  const MyLatLng({required double lat, required double lng})
      : lat = lat.clamp(-90.0, 90.0),
        lng = _normalizeLongitude(lng);

  static double _normalizeLongitude(double lng) {
    if (lng >= -180.0 && lng < 180.0) return lng; // ok

    return ((lng + 180.0) % 360.0) - 180.0;
  }

}

But this
error: Invalid constant value. 

So there question is Is there any way to make human readable const constructor

I think this is the relevant language proposal: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/2222

@TSR There currently is no way in Dart to indicate that a function can and should be evaluated at compilation time and can return a compile-time constant.  Without a way to do that in the language, every function call must be assumed to be able to return different values (or to have side-effects) and be non-constant.

Because calling a function is not a constant operation.
The set of expressions that can be used as constants is limited to operations on numbers and a few other operations on SDK defined values. It is not allowed to run arbitrary user code, and calling a user-written function falls into that category.
